# Call Controller from ajax - Typo3

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fluid, typo3-7.6.x

I have a fluid template.I have to load a select box in change of another select box.I am using ajax to call the second select box.
 My ajax call is something like this

```
$('#bank_name_input').change(function(){
            var val = $('bank_name_input').val();
            var controllerpath ='<f:uri.action action="action_name" controller="controller_name" />';
            jQuery.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url: controllerpath,
                data:{'uid':val},
                success:function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                },
            });
    });
```

It results a 404 - page not found error.

Comment: Check your generated URL in the http request in the browser (dev tools) and try visiting it directly.  So far it's not really an AJAX problem. Also, your selector is missing the hash on line 2.

Comment: http://localhost/my_instance/%3Cf:uri.action%20controller=%22Flight%22%20action=%22getPaymentMethod%22%20/%3E  - this is the url generated.The '#' is not the problem.

Comment: Can you spell out the complete URL?

Comment: localhost/my_instance/%3Cf:uri.action%20controller=%22Flight%22%20action=%22getPaymentMethod%22%20/%3E

Comment: Your fluid syntax is not interpreted because fluid gets confused by the JS curly braces. Try wrapping every bit of JS in <![CDATA[ ]]> tags until you get a proper URL.

Comment: I got another Solution for my problem.The fluid can't understand the js.The fluid uri can be stored in a hidden variable like <f:form.hidden name="uri_hidden" id="uri_hidden" value="<f:uri.action controller='Flight' action='getPaymentMethod' />" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got another Solution for my problem.The fluid can't understand the js.The fluid uri can be stored in a hidden variable like

```
<f:form.hidden name="uri_hidden" id="uri_hidden" value="<f:uri.action controller='your_controller' action='your_action' />" />
```

This value can be access using jquery and this value can be passes as the url in ajaxcall.

```
$('#bank_name_input').change(function(){
            var val = $('#bank_name_input').val();
            var controllerpath = $("#uri_hidden").val();
            jQuery.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url: controllerpath,
                data:{'uid':val},
                success:function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                },
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The real answer is, Fluid and JavaScript don't mix well. JS curly braces need to be escaped by CDATA tags. To get around this, spell out the URL without using a ViewHelper, e.g. "?tx_myextension_myplugin[action]=. myAction&...". This generates the current page with the included plugin using these parameters.

Use typeNum to get a clean response (not the entire page).
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Page/Index.html#typenum

See this example for reference:

http://www.lukasjakob.com/typo3-ajax-request-with-pagetype/

Comment: You're welcome! For future reference: there is no need for thank you comments on SO. Just marking as the correct answer is good enough.